# How to run steamworks example on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, steam

1. I downloaded [the Steamworks SDK](https://partner.steamgames.com/downloads/steamworks_sdk_134.zip).
2. There is a Steamworks example inside. When I execute command `make` in `steamworksexample` folder it fails with errors:

   ```
   steam/sdk/steamworksexample$ make steam/sdk/steamworksexample/../tools/linux/bin/g++ -g -DPOSIX -DSDL -I/home/steam/sdk/steamworksexample/../tools/linux/runtime/i386/usr/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT -DGNUC -O0 -I/home/steam/sdk/steamworksexample/../public -DDEBUG   -c Inventory.cpp -o debug/Inventory.o -MD -MF debug/Inventory.dep
   ```

   > Inventory.cpp: In member function 'void CSpaceWarLocalInventory::OnSteamInventoryFullUpdate(SteamInventoryFullUpdate_t*)':
   >   Inventory.cpp:61:61: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
   >   Inventory.cpp: In member function 'void CSpaceWarLocalInventory::OnSteamInventoryResult(SteamInventoryResultReady_t*)':
   >   Inventory.cpp:131:62: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
   >   Inventory.cpp: In member function 'void CSpaceWarLocalInventory::DoExchange()':
   >   Inventory.cpp:218:18: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
   >   Inventory.cpp: In member function 'void CSpaceWarLocalInventory::GrantTestItems()':
   >   Inventory.cpp:243:35: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
   >   Inventory.cpp: In member function 'const CSpaceWarItem* CSpaceWarLocalInventory::GetItem(SteamItemInstanceID_t) const':
   >   Inventory.cpp:254:9: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
   >   Inventory.cpp: In member function 'const CSpaceWarItem* CSpaceWarLocalInventory::GetInstanceOf(SteamItemDef_t) const':
   >   Inventory.cpp:276:9: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
   >   Inventory.cpp: In member function 'void CSpaceWarLocalInventory::RefreshFromServer()':
   >   Inventory.cpp:283:33: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
   >   make: *** [debug/Inventory.o] Error 1
3. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the steamworks example to build and run on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer. I don't have a great fix, but a few hacky solutions.

The short solution was to run (you'll need to modify the include paths here to whatever directory you have this code in):

```
make CFLAGS="-std=c++0x -include /home/bbales2/sdk/public/steam/steamtypes.h -I/home/bbales2/sdk/tools/linux/runtime-release/amd64/usr/include/SDL2/ -DSDL=1"
```

This will compile some things, but will **fail** to compile "glew.c". To compile this file you need to remove the steamtypes include from that make and run it again like so:

```
make CFLAGS="-std=c++0x -I/home/bbales2/sdk/tools/linux/runtime-release/amd64/usr/include/SDL2/ -DSDL=1"
```

After glew.c compiles, the make will fail again. Re-run the first make command and eventually things should finish. Run the example with "debug/SteamworksExample.sh"

---

In more detail, the errors I came across are listed here. We can fix them all with CFLAGS:

```
error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
```

To fix this you need to tell your compiler to be C++11. This is the "-std=c++0x" flag

```
GameEngine.h:129:52: error: 'uint32' has not been declared
GameEngine.h:129:67: error: 'uint32' has not been declared
GameEngine.h:132:52: error: 'byte' has not been declared
GameEngine.h:132:65: error: 'uint32' has not been declared
GameEngine.h:132:80: error: 'uint32' has not been declared
GameEngine.h:135:52: error: 'DWORD' has not been declared
```

There is a header, sdk/public/steam/steamtypes.h that defines these. It's not getting included by default for some reason. This is the "-include /home/bbales2/sdk/public/steam/steamtypes.h" flag.

```
gameenginesdl.h:18:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
```

The SDL headers are missing. Valve includes them in sdk/tools/linux/runtime-release/amd64/usr/include/SDL2/ but the Makefile isn't detecting and adding them. This is the "-I/home/bbales2/sdk/tools/linux/runtime-release/amd64/usr/include/SDL2/" flag.

```
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/home/bbales2/sdk/public/steam/steamtypes.h:107:15: error: variably modified 'Salt_t' at file scope
/home/bbales2/sdk/public/steam/steamtypes.h:123:1: error: initializer element is not constant
make: *** [debug/glew.o] Error 1
```

We get this error because we can't include steamtypes.h while compiling this file (using the -include flag to force includes like this is not a great idea). Just removing the steamtypes include, re-running make to compile this file, and then adding the steamtypes include back (for the rest of the compile) seems to work.

And

```
Main.cpp:248:2: error: #error Need CreateGameEngine()
... (bunch of Warnings)
Main.cpp: In function 'int RealMain(const char*, HINSTANCE, int)':
Main.cpp:251:2: error: expected primary-expression before 'if'
Main.cpp:251:2: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'if'
make: *** [debug/Main.o] Error 1
```

Main.cpp seems to want us to define the SDL macro. We do that with "-DSDL=1"